# Programming a 3 Body Problem using matlab

Tags: matlab, methods, numerical, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to program a 3 body problem using matlab. I was given the formula for the moon's trajectory in its rotational frame in space. It's basically the ydotdot, xdotdot=GM/(x^2+y^2)^3/2 formula. What the formula is, is not that important.

THe problem I am facing is that, I am supposed to code up a program that will numerically solve the moon's trajectory equation. I'm using ODE45 to compare with since my goal is to get the same results as ODE45. My ultimate problem is that, I want to iterate through time in terms of days so tspan= [0 365]. The thins is when I convert Gravitational constant to seconds and then do tspace= [0 365] I get a completely different result then If I were to do [0  365*3600*34] representing the seconds in a year and G= 6.67e-11. It seems that my units are very weird.

I was wondering if anyone can explain why this is happening when I use ODE 45. Why can't I convert seconds to days clearly using ODE45? Is there an extra step I have to do? The only other variables in my problem is radius, distance, and the mass of the 3 bodies.

Thank you so much. I've been working on this for a very very long time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the 3-body problem an NP-Complete problem?

Comment: @sonic: The general 3-body problem does not have a closed-form solution, which may be what you're thinking of.  The work done at each time step is naively O(N^2), where N is the number of bodies, since you need to calculate the forces between each pair of bodies to determine the positions at the next time step.

Answer (score 3):

That formula for gravitational acceleration along each axis isn't correct.

Put the earth, with mass M_e, at the origin, with the moon (mass M_m) at (x,y).  Then
the earth-moon distance is given by:

```
R_em = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
```

The total earth-moon force is given by:

```
F_em = G*M_e*M_m/R_em^2
```

The total acceleration due to Earth's gravity is given by:

```
a_em = F_em/M_m = G*M_e/R_em^2
```

and is directed toward the origin.  The acceleration along
each axis is then:

```
xdotdot = -F_em*cos(theta) = -F_em*x/R_em = -G*M_e*x/R_em^(3/2)
ydotdot = -F_em*sin(theta) = -F_em*y/R_em = -G*M_e*y/R_em^(3/2)
```

Note the x and y factors, which are missing from the formula you stated.

I'm not sure what you mean by "converting the gravitational constant to seconds".
The value you're using for G has units of newton-meter^2/kg^2.  So it's already
expressed in the MKS (meter-kilogram-second) system, and the accelerations calculated
using this value will have units of meters/sec^2.

With a third body (say, the sun) at (x_s, y_s), you compute a new R_s representing
the moon-sun distance, and compute new acceleration vectors as above, using the
sun's mass M_s (except the acceleration is now in the direction of (x_s, y_s), rather than (0,0)).  The accelerations of the moon from the gravity of the earth and the sun just add component-wise, once everything is put into a common coordinate system (here, 
geocentric coordinates -- although heliocentric might be a more convenient choice, if you're simulating the sun-earth-moon system).  That, plus the initial positions and velocities, should be all you need to compute the positions and velocities at the next time step.